# Hiding a specific table in .net webforms when button is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, sqldatasource

I have two tables connected to different sqldatasources, but I would like only one of them to be displayed when a certain button is clicked.

I tried hiding the tables using a Jquery plugin, but this hides both tables.

I am expecting the first table to be hidden, and the second one to be displayed when a button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using panels you can use .visible

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Panel1.Visible = true;
            Panel2.Visible = false;
        }
```